# Styling WMS layers in GeoServer with fields using "%" character

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have an Oracle Spatial 11g geodatabase connected to GeoServer 2.8 through Oracle plugin. Some feature classes have field names with `%` (percent) characters, e.g. `NAME%EN` or `AREA%KM2`.

The layer shows up correctly and all its attributes are passed with GetFeatureInfo request. However, I cannot use SLD styling that is based on those fields (e.g. creating thematic map based on `AREA%KM2` field).

Does anyone have experience with tables using field names with `%` characters? They are accepted by Oracle naming standards so I hoped GeoServer will handle them too.

Comment: Can you add the error message from the log file.

Comment: The basic error is as follows:
2015-11-01 20:57:11,475 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2015-11-01 20:57:11,480 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: The requested Style can not be used with this layer.  The style specifies an attribute of R$POP$DENSITY and the layer is: test:AREAS

Comment: I tried also with SLD Rest Service (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/sldservice/index.html), which returned the following errors: 2015-10-31 02:56:55,419 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - Error generating Classification!
2015-10-31 02:56:55,419 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/plain

Comment: Your layer name must be a valid xml name see http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Re-Geoserver-devel-wms-getCapabilities-special-characters-td5160099.html but % is illegal

Comment: Layer name does not contain "%", only some field names do. "%" is accepted by Oracle. Moreover, SLD XML file created based on such field names also validates correctly in Geoserver...

Comment: Error message is definitely about a changed name though, could be Oracle or GeoServer, what does getFeatureInfo show?

Comment: getFeatureInfo shows all fields, with their names (including "%") and respective values. No errors.

Answer (score 3):

You might be affected by this ticket: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5176
In other words, it might well be that we have to quote the attribute names when writing queries

Comment: Sounds like a similar issue. So far tried to quote the attributes inside SLD and it didn't help: <ServiceException>The requested Style can not be used with this layer. The style specifies an attribute of &quot;R$POP$DENSITY&quot; and the layer is: test:AREAS</ServiceException>

Comment: Only a code change can add quotes around the attributes